# Minimum supported Gradle version is 4.4. Current version is 4.3

Tags: android-studio, gradle, build.gradle

I have seen multiple questions of the same issue, but none have fixed the issue.

When trying to build the gradle, I get the error as the title says:

```
Minimum supported Gradle version is 4.4. Current version is 4.3.
```

But when I checked the gradle wrapper, it is already 4.4
Even the distributionUrl is already set as:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.4-all.zip
```

The classPath is set to:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'
```

Is there anything else I could do?

Comment: Is your IDE set to use the wrapper, or a locally installed Gradle?

Comment: It is set to use the default gradle wrapper

Comment: clean and rebuild worked for me